# How do I fill a drop down-list based on selection by another drop-down list ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two drop-down lists and I am trying to make a dynamic drop-down list where the user selects the Preference Type from the drop-down list and the input for the Staff Preference Value drop-down list will display the selections for the different Preference Type that the User chooses.

For example; User chooses "Days" in the Preference Type.
Preference Value drop-down list will display hard coded option list with "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday"

OR

User chooses "Branch Location" in the Preference Type.
Preference Value drop-down list will display hard coded option list with "North, South, East, West"

[How it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy51N.png)

My current code is like this. I am using a StaffPreferenceModel to get and set all the items that are in the view page right now. I am not sure how to make a dynamic drop-down list for each of the different selections.

StaffPreferenceModel

```
public class StaffPreferenceModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Staff Preference ID")]
    public Guid StaffPreferenceID { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Preference Type ID")]
    public Guid PreferenceTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreferenceTypeID")]
    public PreferenceTypeModel PreferenceTypes { get; set; }



    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Staff Preference Status ..")]
    [Display(Name = "Staff Preference Value")]
    public string StaffPreferenceValue { get; set; }



    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Prefered Date ..")]
    [Display(Name = "Staff Preference Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StaffPreferenceSetDate { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Branch Zone ID")]
    public Guid BranchZoneID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BranchZoneID")]
    public BranchZoneModel BranchZones { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Staff ID")]
    public Guid StaffID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StaffID")]
    public StaffModel Staffs { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Work Desciption ID")]
    public Nullable<Guid> WorkDescriptionID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkDescriptionID")]
    public WorkDescriptionModel WorkDescriptions { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
 public IActionResult CreateStaffPreference()
    {

        ViewData["BranchZoneID"] = new SelectList(_context.BranchZone, "BranchZoneID", "BranchZoneName");
        ViewData["PreferenceTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.PreferenceType, "PreferenceTypeID", "PreferenceName");
        ViewData["StaffID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName");
        ViewData["WorkDescriptionID"] = new SelectList(_context.WorkDescription, "WorkDescriptionID", "WorkDescriptionName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateStaffPreference([Bind("StaffPreferenceID,PreferenceTypeID,StaffPreferenceValue,StaffPreferenceSetDate,BranchZoneID,StaffID,WorkDescriptionID")] StaffPreferenceModel staffPreferenceModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            staffPreferenceModel.StaffPreferenceID = Guid.NewGuid();
            _context.Add(staffPreferenceModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ProfilePage));
        }
        ViewData["BranchZoneID"] = new SelectList(_context.BranchZone, "BranchZoneID", "BranchZoneName", staffPreferenceModel.BranchZoneID);
        ViewData["PreferenceTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.PreferenceType, "PreferenceTypeID", "PreferenceName", staffPreferenceModel.PreferenceTypeID);
        ViewData["StaffID"] = new SelectList(_context.Staff, "StaffID", "StaffName", staffPreferenceModel.StaffID);
        ViewData["WorkDescriptionID"] = new SelectList(_context.WorkDescription, "WorkDescriptionID", "WorkDescriptionName", staffPreferenceModel.WorkDescriptionID);
        return View(staffPreferenceModel);
    }
```

View Page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateStaffPreference">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PreferenceTypeID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="PreferenceTypeID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PreferenceTypeID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffPreferenceValue" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffPreferenceValue" class="form-control" /></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffPreferenceValue" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffPreferenceSetDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffPreferenceSetDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffPreferenceSetDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="WorkDescriptionID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="WorkDescriptionID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.WorkDescriptionID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BranchZoneID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="BranchZoneID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.BranchZoneID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StaffID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <a asp-action="ProfilePage" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"><i class=" fa fa-table"></i>Back to List</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create an event handle by ajax on selection of Preference Type. Get list for Preference Value dropdown inside that event (ActioneResult) and return it to populate in the dropdown.

Comment: Hi, @zan berzanus, if the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Please follow up.Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: @MichelleWang Hi, I am still not able to get this feature done. I'm in the process of figuring out! Thank you

Comment: Hi, @zan berzanus, I can't see the needs of cascading, Did you mean the values of  drop-down list all from StaffPreferenceModel ? If so, it's easier than before.

Comment: What's the way of switching StaffPreferenceModel? By redirecting a page or Dopdownlist cascading . It's important to code ajax function. Please detail more operation logic so that we can help.

Comment: @MichelleWang I have updated my question, if you would take a look at it! Yes the value for the drop down lists are all in the StaffPreferenceModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 24/07** 
Here is the result of mini version.
[image]

If it meets your needs, you could follow the steps below to accomplish it.

> 1. Model

There's no need to add `PreferenceType`in `StaffPreferenceModel` because it's only used to display the group of `PreferenceValue`.

```
public class StaffPreferenceModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Staff Preference ID")]
    public Guid StaffPreferenceID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preference Value ID")]
    public Guid PreferenceValueID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreferenceValueID")]
    public PreferenceValueModel PreferenceValue { get; set; }

}

public class PreferenceTypeModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Preference Type ID")]
    public Guid PreferenceTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preference Type")]
    public string PreferenceName { get; set; }
}

public class PreferenceValueModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Preference Value ID")]
    public Guid PreferenceValueID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preference Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preference Type ID")]
    public Guid PreferenceTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreferenceTypeID")]
    public PreferenceTypeModel PreferenceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

> 2. Controller

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["PreferenceTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.PreferenceTypeModel, "PreferenceTypeID", "PreferenceName");

        //list preference values by default type
        var preferenceValues = _context.PreferenceValueModel.Where(p=>p.PreferenceTypeID == _context.PreferenceTypeModel.FirstOrDefault().PreferenceTypeID);
        ViewData["PreferenceValueID"] = new SelectList(preferenceValues, "PreferenceValueID", "Value");

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<List<PreferenceValueModel>> GetPreferenceValues(Guid id)
    {
        var PreferenceValues = _context.PreferenceValueModel.Where(p => p.PreferenceTypeID == id).ToList();
        return PreferenceValues;
    }
```

> 3. View

```
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">PreferenceType</label>
            <select id="PreferenceType" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PreferenceTypeID"></select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PreferenceValueID" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="PreferenceValueID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PreferenceValueID"></select>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Use js to get `preference values` when `PreferenceType` dropdownlist selected**.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
          $("#PreferenceType").change(function () {
              $("#PreferenceValueID").empty();
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '@Url.Action("GetPreferenceValues")', // we are calling json method
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: { id: $("#PreferenceType").val() },
                  success: function (states) {
                      // states contains the JSON formatted list
                      // of states passed from the controller

                      $("#PreferenceValueID").append('<option value="' + "0" + '">' + "Select PreferenceValue" + '</option>');
                      debugger;
                      $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                          $("#PreferenceValueID").append('<option value="' + state.preferenceValueID + '">' + state.value + '</option>');
                          // here we are adding option for States
                      });

                  },
                  error: function (ex) {
                      alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                  }
              });
              return false;
          })
      });
</script>
```

---

Cascading a `DropDownList` with another `DropDownList` in ASP.Net.

Please try to read this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/cascading-one-dropdownlist-with-other-dropdownlist-in-asp-ne/) and if you are using `razor pages` in `MVC`, read [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/filter-grid-with-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-using-razor/) article.

The main steps:

1. Create **Entity Data Model**   (`Preference` and `StaffPreference`)
2. Adding **View Model** (`PreferenceView`)

   ```
   public class PreferenceView
    {
        public int PreferenceId { get; set; }
        public List<Preference> PreferenceList { get; set; }
        public List<StaffPreference> StaffPreferenceList { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. Create `action` to return `view` with `PreferenceView`.
   **Create a `GetStaffPreferenceByType` method to return StaffPreferenceList  by type.**
4. Adding jQuery Ajax script for binding State dropdownlist.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me a lot, I'm sorry for the late replies ! But I have tried it and it works, It is very helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Hi the code works, I need to ask whether I have to make another separate table in the SQL Database for "Preference Value" as I have an error for when I try to go to the page, it says: " SqlException: Invalid object name 'PreferenceValue'. "

Comment: I think it's no need to create new table. From the PreferenceValueModel, we can see the "Value" is real object name in database  not "PreferenceValue".